# iphone: submit app with iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I've an app that is built in Xcode 4.2 (developer preview) and iOS 5, with deployment target iOS 4.0. I'm not using any of the iOS 5.0 features. Can I submit this build to Apple? Or is this a problem because it's beta? Should I go back to Xcode 4.02 and build it on 4.3?

Comment: In the Apple Developer Forums, where it's currently legal to discuss all things iOS5, you can find your answer here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/449553

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should **absolutely never** install beta builds SDKs as your primary SDK and version of XCode. Always keep the current install under /Developer (or wherever you choose) and install the beta in some other location (/iOS5Beta as an example). With this, when the new beta versions of XCode and the SDK arrive, you can uninstall the /iOS5Beta version and install the new one (may not have to uninstall, but just a point).

This allows you to beta test, then under the /Developer install do your regular development.

When the GM is out, you install that under /Developer and go.

You **never** submit Apps to Apple with beta builds of XCode and the SDKs.

Comment: hi there. Maybe you know about how to submit app from iOS5 SDK downgraded to iOS4 SDK? Its all about ARC management. Can you advice please? Thank you.

Comment: @Eugene I have the same issue, see here for a way (untested by me) to compile in XCode 4.1 with ARC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361824/is-there-any-way-to-use-llvm-3-in-xcode-4-1

Answer (score 2):

Every readme file I remember for beta versions of Xcode have said they can't be used for submission. You have to use a GA version of Xcode to submit apps.