# Developed an app with ARC and xcode 4.2. How can I submit this to iTunes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

After reading:

[iphone: submit app with iOS 5 and XCode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332511/iphone-submit-app-with-ios-5-and-xcode-4-2)

I realize that using ARC and expecting to release an app to the app store with this technology might have been a bit short-sighted of me. What is the best course of action for me?

- Use Xcode 4 and redo the memory management
- Wait for Xcode 4.2 to be released
- Some other magical way that will solve all my issues and make my dreams come true

Thanks for the advice.

**Update**: Just in case anyone wandered on to this, it was while Xcode 4.2 was still in beta.  End result: don't use beta features unless you're ok with waiting for the final release.

Comment: Same situation here :( waiting for "Let's talk iphone" event tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, first, there is no Santa Claus. That leaves us with:

How urgently do you want to ship?

Xcode 4.2 is going to ship with iOS 5. iOS 5 is likely to ship around September. It could be later. So can you sit on your app for that long? If so, eh, keep polishing, maybe work on some additional features, do an exhaustive run of QA, then when the GM is ready you'll be all set.

If you want to be the master of your own destiny and ship on your terms, install Xcode 4.1 and run the static analyzer to get the full measure of your missing memory management, spend a few hours fixing things up, then profile and test the hell out of it just to be sure. Read up on the Leaks instrument, along with [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), should you run into unexpected memory issues (dunno how big your project is, but I'm sure they can build up with the luxury of ARC snatched away).