# Is there any way to use LLVM 3 in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction, llvm

I wonder, since LLVM 3.0 is readily available and officially released, is there a way to compile with LLVM 3 when using Xcode 4.1. It would help alot since I used ARC and my app development turned out to be finished sooner than planned. So I don't have to wait until next Xcode 4.2 is released to upload my app to Apple review. Thanks

Comment: You are aware that there's only limited ARC support on iOS < 5, since for full ARC support runtime support is needed ?

Comment: The only thing missing in iOS 4.3 is weak linking automatic nulling, all else is there.

Comment: just as a comment - I developed another quite complex app with ARC and tested it also with allocation instruments and everything is absolutely working fine - didn't have to take care of all this assembler like memeory mgmt stuff with ARC - development is much faster than before! I guess live will change with the new release :;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily compile with any compiler you want with Xcode; see http://mattrajca.com/post/8749868513/llvm-code-coverage-and-xcode-4 , for example.  IIRC, you aren't allowed to submit an app that isn't using a compiler bundled with an official Xcode release, though.

Comment: "you aren't allowed to submit an app that isn't using a compiler bundled with an official Xcode release" <--- I'm trying to find the source for that information. Where can I find this, is it in the developer agreement?

Comment: Also, this technique doesn't appear to work with ARC. If ARC is enabled, you get the error `file not found: /opt/local/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a` on compile.