# Is it possible to use NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSNumber "literals" in Xcode 4.3? (LLVM 4.0)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

Apparently, the new Objective-C literals have landed into the [clang trunk](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/?view=log&pathrev=152137), and thus lifted the shadowy veil of any NDA's.

**My question**…  HOW can I, *in God's name*, use these constructs (see below) in Xcode ⋜ v4.3.  If not, and I'm stuck waiting for the XCode 4.4 / OSX 10.8 / LLVM 4.0 trifecta, could the same functionality be jerry-rigged somehow - via some clever categories, etc.?

(For all y'all that don't know… these new syntaxes mean that there will be the much-appreciated [additional constructs for creating](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/13/new-objectivec-literal-syntax/) `NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSNumber`.)

Comment: It's quite likely that the answer to [Is there any way to use LLVM 3 in Xcode 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361824/is-there-any-way-to-use-llvm-3-in-xcode-4-1) still largely applies. I think there are other similar questions linked from there, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a non-official way to do this…  Using the [Lumumba Framework on github](https://github.com/Tharabas/Lumumba), there is a whole kit'n'caboodle of Syntactic sugar categories that had the following defines… which achieve the desired effect.

```
#define $(...)        ((NSString *)[NSString  stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__,nil])
#define $array(...)   ((NSArray *)[NSArray arrayWithObjects:__VA_ARGS__,nil])
#define $set(...)     ((NSSet *)[NSSet setWithObjects:__VA_ARGS__,nil])
#define $map(...)     ((NSDictionary *)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:__VA_ARGS__,nil])
#define $int(A)       [NSNumber numberWithInt:(A)]
#define $ints(...)    [NSArray arrayWithInts:__VA_ARGS__,NSNotFound]
#define $float(A)     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(A)]
#define $doubles(...) [NSArray arrayWithDoubles:__VA_ARGS__,MAXFLOAT]
#define $words(...)   [[@#__VA_ARGS__ splitByComma] trimmedStrings]
#define $concat(A,...) { A = [A arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:((NSArray *)[NSArray arrayWithObjects:__VA_ARGS__,nil])]; }
```

So, basically, instead of…

```
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    object, @"aWord", [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], nil];
```

It's just…

```
NSArray *anArray = $array(object, @"aWord", $int(7));
```

Ahhh, brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is Xcode 4.4 only.

Comment: How would it depend on the version of the IDE? Xcode has nothing to do with this. It depends on the compiler version.

Comment: This is not a very useful answer; support for the syntax comes from the compiler, which _is_ available. The question is essentially how a different compiler than the default can be used in Xcode.

Comment: The way the question was asked, I assume XCode is not seen as the IDE, but the application you download. In the application, there comes llvm 3.0 (see Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang)