# Using new Objective-C literals

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I use the new Objective-C literals described here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html ?
I have XCode 4.3 installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSNumber "literals" in Xcode 4.3? (LLVM 4.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064311/is-it-possible-to-use-nsarray-nsdictionary-and-nsnumber-literals-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Users of Apple compiler releases can use these features starting with the Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0. Xcode 4.3 uses compiler version 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode 4.3, you cant. Upgrade to either 4.4 or 4.5 to use these features

Comment: Yes, Xcode 4.4 and 4.5 are basically the same except 4.5 comes with the iOS 6 SDK packaged in.

Comment: How do I update Xcode to 4.4/.5? Going into the App Store, under updates section, it tells me all apps are up to date

Comment: It's a developer preview at the moment, you need to get the download from the [developer center](https://developer.apple.com/)

Comment: This is not correct. The literal syntax is a compiler feature (not tied to Xcode itself in any way), and the clang version that supports it is public. All you have to do is swap the compiler that Xcode uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361824/is-there-any-way-to-use-llvm-3-in-xcode-4-1