# Literal @YES not working in iOS 5 / Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm, literals, llvm-4.0

New Xcode 4.4 is out and it should support literals like

`@42`
`@"String"`
`@23.0L`
`@{ @"key" : obj }` and
`@[obj1, obj2]`

and it should also support `@YES` and `@NO`, which isn't working when targeting latest iOS 5 (and prior).
After compiling it show the error message:

> Unexpected type name 'BOOL': expected expression

I know you can fix it by typing `@(YES)` and `@(NO)`. But I want to know the reason why it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason is Apple forgot the parentheses here:

```
#define YES             (BOOL)1
```

This will be fixed in iOS 6 SDK:

```
#define YES             ((BOOL)1)
```

In the meantime you must type `@(YES)`.

Comment: It should be noted that this needs to be done after the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`— if one puts these #defines in their Prefix.pch, they should make sure to import Foundation earlier in the pch.

Answer (score 9):

[This](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) is useful for information about literals.

A commenter on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428213/916299) also points out:

> There is one small thing I'd like to warn about. Literal bools are also not supported 
>   because of this. However, a quick fix that I implemented was adding
>   this to the beginning of one of my common headers (in an iOS project)
>
> ```
> #ifndef __IPHONE_6_0 
> #if __has_feature(objc_bool) 
> #undef YES 
> #undef NO 
> #define YES __objc_yes 
> #define NO __objc_no 
> #endif 
> #endif
> ```

@phix23s answer seems to be more to the point. You should accept that.

This was worth adding from comments:

> It should be noted that this needs to be done after the #import . If one puts these #defines in their Prefix.pch, they should make sure to import Foundation earlier in the pch

Comment: that question is referring to subscripting, which is only available in iOS 6 because it is more than syntactic sugar. number/bool/collection literals should be available in previous versions

Comment: Hmm - interesting - I just converted my ios5.0 project to the new literals, and all but subscripting is working just fine.

Comment: Well, there is a way to get it all now - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11694878/96716. I included your code above with attribution and link.

Comment: I like this answer more— it's a nice “polyfill” approach, rather than a wait-it-out one.

Comment: Also, like @phix23's answer, it should be noted that this needs to be done after the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`— if one puts these #defines in their Prefix.pch, they should make sure to import Foundation earlier in the pch.