# Since when do we have such useful creators for NSArray and NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I discovered today that there is a much less tedious way to create arrays and dictionaries on the fly:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];

NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"key": @"value", @"key2": @"value2"};
```

Is this a rather new addition to the objective-c language and what is the name of these constructs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New as of Xcode 4.4. I've heard them referred to as collection literals.

EDIT to add:

You can also reference members of NSArray and NSDictionary as `array[1]` and `dictionary[@"key"]`. The creation syntax is backwards compatible as it is fully expanded at build. The accessor syntax is not as it involves changes to the runtime.

Comment: You can only do the referencing at this time on Lion and iOS 5 by extending the capabilities of the runtime, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11694878/96716

Answer (score 2):

They are part of Apple's LLVM 4.0 compiler, which shipped in XCode 4.4.

More information can be found [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) on LLVM's website, under the "Grammar Additions" section. Other new literal syntax exist as well, which is also documented on the website.

Answer (score 2):

Ye.. there are some [other examples](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
// character literals.
  NSNumber *theLetterZ = @'Z';          // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithChar:'Z']

  // integral literals.
  NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;             // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]
  NSNumber *fortyTwoUnsigned = @42U;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:42U]
  NSNumber *fortyTwoLong = @42L;        // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLong:42L]
  NSNumber *fortyTwoLongLong = @42LL;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:42LL]

  // floating point literals.
  NSNumber *piFloat = @3.141592654F;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.141592654F]
  NSNumber *piDouble = @3.1415926535;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.1415926535]

  // BOOL literals.
  NSNumber *yesNumber = @YES;           // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
  NSNumber *noNumber = @NO;             // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
```

I first saw it on java! Kinda cool :)