# AIR Native Extension failing on NSDictionary objectForKeyedSubscript in iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, ios5, air-native-extension

Creating an Adobe AIR Native Extension that uses the following objC code will crash in iOS 5.1

```
NSDictionary *value=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"aSampleValue",@"aSampleKey",nil];    
NSLog(@"Try objectForKeyedSubscript: %@", [value objectForKeyedSubscript:@"aSampleKey"]);
```

It will fail with "[__NSCFDictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector"

I've got it working right now using Method Swizzling to remap NSDictionary objectForKeyedSubscript: to valueForKey: (if it doesn't exist) but I'm not super happy with that workaround.  There's got to be a platform.xml option or compiler flag that will not strip these function calls in iOS 5.1 but I can't find anything.  My

Note: This problem might look a lot like the following (and a few others, but I don't have the rep for the links) but it's not because a native xCode project works fine, but an ANE compiled with ADT does not.

Things tried and failed:

- [How to enable the new Objective-C object literals on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658669/how-to-enable-the-new-objective-c-object-literals-on-ios)
- [objectForKeyedSubscript: crash on iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544629/objectforkeyedsubscript-crash-on-ios-5-1)

---

**SPECS**

**FlashBuilder/AIR:**
SDK3.7
ADT -version: 3.7.0.1530

**xCode project**
BaseSDK: 6.1 (latest)
Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s
Deployment Target: iOS 5.1

**Platform.XML**
(it's pretty long since it has some other support requirements)

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.7">
    <linkerOptions>
    <option>-ObjC</option>
    <option>-weak_framework Accounts</option>
    <option>-framework AddressBook</option>
    <option>-framework AddressBookUI</option>
    <option>-weak_framework AdSupport</option>
    <option>-framework CoreLocation</option>
    <option>-framework CoreMotion</option>
    <option>-framework CoreTelephony</option>
    <option>-framework EventKit</option>
    <option>-framework EventKitUI</option>
    <option>-framework iAd</option>
    <option>-framework MapKit</option>
    <option>-framework MediaPlayer</option>
    <option>-framework MessageUI</option>
    <option>-framework OpenAL</option>
    <option>-weak_framework PassKit</option>
    <option>-framework StoreKit</option>
    <option>-weak_framework Twitter</option>
    <option>-framework UIKit</option>
    <option>-lsqlite3</option>
    <option>-lxml2</option>
    <option>-lz</option>
    </linkerOptions>
</platform>
```

**ADT Build Command:**

```
adt -package -target ane build/MyANEName.ane  ANE/extension.xml -swc ANE/MyANEName.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions ANE/platform.xml -C ANE/ios .
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Are the first two lines code that *you* wrote.  If so then just use `objectForKey:` instead.

Comment: There's code that I don't control that uses objectForKeyedSubscript causing the issue. You're right though, if it was all my code it would t be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I solved it by using the `-platformsdk` option for ADT and pointing it to the iOS 6.1 SDK

On OSX this is located here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
```

So add this to your ADT command:

```
-platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
```