# Why does @YES give an "expected expression" error, but @(YES) compiles?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, objective-c-literals

Using XCode 4.4's Convert to Modern Objective C Syntax, my `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` calls were converted to `@(YES)`. I had some issue that I've now forgotten, and changed them myself to `@YES`, which is supposed to be the correct syntax.

However, doing so gives me the error:

> Unexpected type name 'BOOL': expected expression

I know that there is an "expression" syntax but I don't see why I can't simply use `@YES` and `@NO`.

```
// Compiler error:
NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = @{@"hasBeenLaunched": @YES};

// No error
NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = @{@"hasBeenLaunched": @(YES)};
```

Why does `@(YES)` compile while `@YES` does not, and what I can do to remedy that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer:

Use `@(YES)` and `@(NO)`

---

Longer answer:

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686073/916299) which explains that this is mostly appears to be an oversight on Apple's part.

A commenter on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428213/916299) also points out:

> There is one small thing I'd like to warn about. Literal bools are also not supported 
>   because of this. However, a quick fix that I implemented was adding
>   this to the beginning of one of my common headers (in an iOS project)

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_6_0 
#if __has_feature(objc_bool) 
#undef YES 
#undef NO 
#define YES __objc_yes 
#define NO __objc_no 
#endif 
#endif
```

Comment: I see. So I'm not crazy. Thanks for the heads up. I added that to my prefix and was able to use the non-parenthesis syntax, as desired.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in Xcode 4.5 -- using basically that same code, judging by the [LLVM docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 0):

The new number literals (like @YES) in the Clang update are not fully implemented into XCode until 4.5.