# use '[]' syntax to access containers in XCode 4.4 seems not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.4, llvm-4.0

Has anyone tried new syntax sugar introduced in Xcode 4.4 (iOS 5.1), like automatically calls @synthesize or Literal Syntax for NSArray ? They are quite handy.

But I can't get it right for this one , "use '[]' syntax to access". I tried following and they did not work. What did I do wrong ? Thanks.

```
NSArray *tmp = @[@"hello",@"world"];  //This one works fine
NSString *i = tmp[0]; // or tmp[@0];  this one does not work.
```

Comment: What is your deployment target? I believe it has to be >= ios 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two different features there. Your first line (`tmp = @[@"hello",@"world"]`) are literals. That should work in Xcode 4.4.

The second line (`i = tmp[0]`) needs runtime support (there are a couple of extra methods needed to make it work) and so won't work in iOS 5 and below. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425976/objective-c-literals-accessing-nsarray) for more details.