# Using @[array, of, items] vs [NSArray arrayWithObjects:]

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-literals

Is there a difference between

```
NSArray *myArray = @[objectOne, objectTwo, objectThree];
```

and

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objectOne, objectTwo, objectThree, nil];
```

Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between @\[\] and \[NSArray arrayWithObjects:\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834504/difference-between-and-nsarray-arraywithobjects)

Comment: Sorry, I even searched google and here. Maybe the symbols were messing up the search that is why i wasn't getting anything relevant.

Comment: It's not meant to be a recrimination. Actually, that comment is created by the system on my behalf when I vote to close.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are almost identical, but not completely. The Clang documentation on [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) states:

> Array literal expressions expand to calls to
>   `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`, which validates that all objects are
>   non-nil. The variadic form, `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` uses nil as
>   an argument list terminator, which can lead to malformed array
>   objects.

So

```
NSArray *myArray = @[objectOne, objectTwo, objectThree];
```

would throw a runtime exception if `objectTwo == nil`, but

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objectOne, objectTwo, objectThree, nil];
```

would create an array with one element in that case.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer; the difference is subtle, but nevertheless the two are different.

Comment: I'm not sure what "malformed array objects" means, but the arrays would be perfectly fine, just not the length you thought they would be. Also, I sometimes intentionally exploit the nil termination behavior, to have an optional last element that is only included if it is not `nil`.

Answer (score -2):

No. At compile time the `@[...]` literals will be changed to `arrayWithObjects:`

The only difference is that `@[...]` is only supported in newer versions of the LLVM compiler.

Comment: No it is `arrayWithObjects:count:`