# what is the use of @[ ] in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsarray

I have seen

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[objects];
```

when looking at some example code.

What is the meaning of `@[objects]` here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[objects];
```

is the same as

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objects count:count];
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is not the same as `initWithObjects`, but `arrayWithObjects:count:` (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/14527582/1187415). It returns an autoreleased object, and the treatment of `nil` in the list is different.

Answer (score 6):

## It is also known as Literals in Objective-C

```
Examples
Immutable array expression:
NSArray *array = @[ @"Hello", NSApp, [NSNumber numberWithInt:42] ];
```

When using Apple `LLVM` compiler `4.0 or later`, arrays, dictionaries, and numbers `(NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber classes)` can also be created using literal syntax instead of methods.[22] Literal syntax uses the **@ symbol** combined with `[], {}, (),` .

**Example without literals:**

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:someObject];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:someObject forKey:@"key"];
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt];
```

**Example with literals:**

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ someObject ];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{ @"key" : someObject };
NSNumber *myNumber = @(myInt);


objc-at-expression : '@' (string-literal | encode-literal | selector-literal | protocol-literal | object-literal)
                   ;

object-literal : ('+' | '-')? numeric-constant
               | character-constant
               | boolean-constant
               | array-literal
               | dictionary-literal
               ;

boolean-constant : '__objc_yes' | '__objc_no' | 'true' | 'false'  /* boolean keywords. */
                 ;

array-literal : '[' assignment-expression-list ']'
              ;

assignment-expression-list : assignment-expression (',' assignment-expression-list)?
                           | /* empty */
                           ;

dictionary-literal : '{' key-value-list '}'
                   ;

key-value-list : key-value-pair (',' key-value-list)?
               | /* empty */
               ;

key-value-pair : assignment-expression ':' assignment-expression
               ;
```

For more info [Read this Tutorial](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Comment: @Downvoter please leave comment on why the down vote then user can improve answer where needed.

Comment: +1 from me as your answers are generally pretty good and I can't see anything wrong with this so don't believe you deserve a downvote for it.

Comment: Good generalized explanation which helps readers to understand that this isn't relegated to arrays.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a array with one object thats the object "objects"

Answer (score 0):

It is a new feature added to the LLVM compiler. You can create an array with

```
NSArray *array = @[object1, ...];
```

Note that you cannot create a mutable array and that you do not need to end the list of objects with `nil`. Watch the WWDC 2012 video "What's New in LLVM".