# What does @[ mean in objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

For example:

```
[[FlyoutTableViewController alloc] initWithViewControllers:@[@[firstNavigationController],@[secondNavigationController]]];

- (id)initWithViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
```

I know it's sending a NSArray of these view controllers to initWithViewControllers, but I want to know more about this way of creating arrays. What are the benifits, any potential issues etc?

Also, do the objects, firstNavigationController and secondNavigationController need to be inside the @[ too, or what's going on there?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a shorthand way of creating an NSArray.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

is equivalent to

```
NSArray *array = @[];
```

You can see more objective-c literals [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 0):

`@[item1, item2, item3]` is syntax sugar for `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, nil]`. Nothing more than a shorthand. There are no more benefits or issues than with the method it expands to.

You can make arrays of arrays too like that. @[@[item1]] is an array containing a single array containing item1.

Comment: Well, to be precise, it is equivalent to `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`, compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527489/using-array-of-items-vs-nsarray-arraywithobjects.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are defining an array with a values. e.g.

```
@[value1, value2, value3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array literal. Like a string literal `@"My String"`. A shorthand notation for creating arrays. Similar usage and limitations to the `NSString` version (immutable).

So, `@[firstNavigationController]` creates an `NSArray` with a single item in it. And your parameter is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you the analogy.

`"A String"` : C-string

`@"A String"`: Obj-C string (`NSString`)

---

`{1,2}` (not `[1,2]`): C array

`@[@1, @2]` (not `@[1,2]`): Obj-C array (`NSArray with NSNumber elements`)

Comment: Only problem is that ints can't be in an NSArray. Put @s in front of the integers to wrap them.

Comment: True, though I'll keep the answer as it is so people can see your comment :)

Comment: The syntax for a C array is `{1, 2}` -- curly braces, not square. `[1,2]` is invalid.