# Difference between NSArray.array/.new /@[]/alloc-init

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

There seem to be different methods of instantiating NSArrays (same for NSDictionary and some others).

I know:

1. `[NSArray array]`
2. `[NSArray new]`
3. `@[]`
4. `[[NSArray alloc] init]`

For readability reasons I usually stick with `[NSArray array]`, but what is the difference between all those, do they all really do the same?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/difference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527489/using-array-of-items-vs-nsarray-arraywithobjects and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new.

Comment: And how exactly is the question related to [swift]?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Results are same for all of them, you get a new empty **immutable** array. These methods have different memory management implications though. `ARC` makes no difference in the end, but before ARC you would have to use the right version or send appropriate retain, release or autorelease messages.

- `[NSArray new]`, `[[NSArray alloc] init]` return an array with retain count is 1. Before ARC you would have to release or autorelease that array or you'd leak memory.
- `[NSArray array]`, `@[]` return an already autoreleased array (retain count is 0). If you want it to stick around without ARC you'd have to manually retain it or it would be deallocated when the current autorelease pool gets popped.

Answer (score 8):

1. `[NSArray array]` : Create and return an empty array
2. `[NSArray new]`   : `alloc`, `init` and return a `NSArray` object
3. `@[]` : Same as 1.
4. `[[NSArray alloc] init]` : Same as 2.

Different between `[NSArray array]` and `[[NSArray alloc] init]` is if there are non-ARC:

- `[NSArray array]` is an autorelease object. You have to call `retain` if you want to keep it. E.g when you `return` an array.
- `[[NSArray alloc] init]` is an retained object. So you don't have to call `retain` more if you want keep it.

With ARC, they are same.

Comment: it'd make more sense if you could also explain when we should be aware of difference between `[NSArray array];` and `[[NSArray alloc] init];` for instance and why.

Comment: @holex. Thank you. I improved my answer.