# SDWebImage 3 and iOS 5.1 Subscript Compiling error

Tags: objective-c, ios5, sdwebimage

Per the [SDWebImage about](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) SDWebImage 3 supports iOS 5.0 (*"The version 3.0 of SDWebImage isn't fully backward compatible with 2.0 and requires iOS 5.0 minimum deployement version"*).

However, I am having issues compiling it. I added it with Cocoapods to my iOS 5.1 project.

I am getting a compiling error complaining about the subscript syntax, it can be resolved by [adding a category to NSObject to have subscripts in the .pch file, as suggested by Jeff Wolski here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425976/compiler-error-expected-method-not-found-when-using-subscript-on-nsarray).

The specific error is

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type
>   'NSArray *'

It is having that compile error in multiple places, one example is in SDImageCache.m, in the initWithNamespace method:

> NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
>           _diskCachePath = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fullNamespace];

While I am able to compile using Jeff Woski solution, I am concerned that SDWebImage 3 doesn't really support iOS 5.x and while it compiles I might have further issues in runtime.

Does SDWebImage 3 support iOS 5.x? Is there another way to fix the compiling issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might come looking for this information. The solution from Jeff Wolski seems to be appropriate. I have been using it extensively and it doesn't seem to have any issue because of that.

**Update:**

Please note that the base-sdk of the App wasn't iOS 6.0. The deployment target can be iOS 5.0, but the SDK must be 6.0 for it to work.

Using the proper base-sdk it is not necessary to do any workaround.