# How to install the latest version of the apple llvm compiler?

Tags: xcode, llvm

I am new to iOS development. I've recently stumbled upon the new objective-c collection-literals syntax on an article, and I would like to be able to use this newer version of the language. How can I install the newest version of the apple llvm compiler without having to install xCode's newest version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to use LLVM 3 in Xcode 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361824/is-there-any-way-to-use-llvm-3-in-xcode-4-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get LLVM separately from Xcode at [llvm.org](http://llvm.org), though you may find some of the new features don't work well without IDE and framework support.